# ¿Como pasar código de Java a JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java

Estaba haciendo un [ejercicio de encriptación](https://www.aceptaelreto.com/problem/statement.php?id=102) de acepta el reto y necesito pasar este ejercicio de Java a JavaScript y me estoy encontrando con el problema de que en JavaScript me dice "Character is not defined" en distintas líneas. Si alguien pudiese echarme una mano para pasarlo de lenguaje estaría muy agradecido.

**Ejercicio en Java**

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
    String alfabeto = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", entrada, texto1, letra;
    int desencriptar, numeroletra, codificador = alfabeto.indexOf("p");
    do {
        int contador = 0;
        texto1 = "";
        entrada = lector.nextLine();

        desencriptar = codificador - alfabeto.indexOf(entrada.charAt(0));

        if (desencriptar < 0) {
            desencriptar = alfabeto.length() - ((-1) * desencriptar);
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < entrada.length(); i++) {

            numeroletra = alfabeto.indexOf(Character.toLowerCase(entrada.charAt(i)));
            if (numeroletra < 0) {

                letra = "" + entrada.charAt(i);
            } else {

                int codigoNuevo = (numeroletra + desencriptar) % alfabeto.length();
                letra = "" + alfabeto.charAt(codigoNuevo);
            }

            if (Character.isUpperCase(entrada.charAt(i))) {
                texto1 = texto1 + letra.toUpperCase();
            } else {
                texto1 = texto1 + letra;
            }

            if (letra.matches("[aeiouAEIOU]")) {
                contador++;
            }

        }

        if ("FIN".equals(texto1)) {
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println(contador);
        }
    } while (true);
}
```

**Ejercicio en Javascript**

```
var alfabeto = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var entrada;
var texto1;
var letra;
var desencriptar;
var numeroletra;

var codificador = alfabeto.indexOf("p");

    var contador = 0;
    texto1 = "";
    entrada = prompt("Mensaje: ");

    desencriptar = codificador - alfabeto.indexOf(entrada.charAt(0));

    if (desencriptar < 0) {
        desencriptar = alfabeto.length - ((-1) * desencriptar);
    }

    for (var i = 1; i < entrada.length; i++) {

        numeroletra = alfabeto.indexOf(String.prototype.charAt(i));
        if (numeroletra < 0) {

            letra = "" + entrada.charAt(i);
        } else {
            var codigoNuevo = (numeroletra + desencriptar) % alfabeto.length;
            letra = "" + alfabeto.charAt(codigoNuevo);
        }

        if (String.prototype.charAt(i)) {
            texto1 = texto1 + letra.toUpperCase();
        } else {
            texto1 = texto1 + letra;
        }

        if (letra.match(/[aeiou]/gi).length) {
            contador++;
        }    }    console.log(contador)
```

Comment: No lo coloco como respuesta debido a que no estoy seguro, pero según entiendo Character es u método que tenia el código java como no existe en tu código de JavaScript por eso te dice que no esta definida, diria yo que el equivalente es `String.prototype.charAt()`

Comment: Qué caracter es el que dice que no está definido?

Comment: El String.prototype.charAt() ha funcionado pero ahora el error me lo da en el             `if (letra.matches("[aeiouAEIOU]"))`   . Me dice:  _letra.matches is not a function_   He pensado que seria problema de la expresión regular pero no es ese el fallo.

Comment: agrega tu codigo javascript para ver lo que tienes

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-LOzmbkgBeUIt8tiCU1Rm6U_iv_6Rdw6EH2Apbj5MWU/edit?usp=sharing   Aqui esta mi codigo

Comment: Usa "aeiou".includes(letra.toLowerCase())

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Java y javascript son dos lenguajes totalmente diferentes que tienen una sintaxis parecida. No esperes poder hacer pasar uno por otro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ver checalo

Los `charAt(0)` solo se cambian por el `string[posición]`

`lector.nextLine();` se cambia por `prompt("Entrada", "");`

`.length()` por `.length`

`letra.matches("[aeiouAEIOU]")` por `"aeiou".includes(letra.toLowerCase())`

`Character.isUpperCase(entrada.charAt(i))` por `entrada[i] == entrada[i].toUpperCase()`

El for lo puse en 0 no se si lo pusiste en 1 apropósito para que empezara desde la segunda posición.

```
<script>

    let alfabeto = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", entrada, texto1, letra;
    let desencriptar, numeroletra, codificador = alfabeto.indexOf("p");
    let contador = 0;

    while(true){
    texto1 = "";
    entrada = prompt("Entrada", "");

    desencriptar = codificador - alfabeto.indexOf(entrada[0]);

        if (desencriptar < 0) {
            desencriptar = alfabeto.length - ((-1) * desencriptar);
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < entrada.length; i++) {

            numeroletra = alfabeto.indexOf(entrada[i].toLowerCase());
            if (numeroletra < 0) {

                letra = "" + entrada[i];
            } else {

                let codigoNuevo = (numeroletra + desencriptar) % alfabeto.length;
                letra = "" + alfabeto[codigoNuevo];
            }

            if (entrada[i] == entrada[i].toUpperCase()) {
                texto1 = texto1 + letra.toUpperCase();
            } else {
                texto1 = texto1 + letra;
            }

            if ("aeiou".includes(letra.toLowerCase())) {
                contador++;
            }

        }

        if ("FIN" == texto1) {
            break;
        } else {
            console.log(contador);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Me sirvió, muchísimas gracias!

Comment: De nada. Saludos

Comment: @JorgeLuis gracias por editar tu respuesta, será de ayuda a la comunidad,saludos.